# bind / named error

Tags: ubuntu, dns, plesk, named, nameservers

I got an error I somehow can't get rid of.

Maybe smbd can help me work this out.
I got Plesk 11 running on an Ubuntu machine.

The DNS is up running and working, but whenever I wanna restart it, I get the following error:

root@mach:~# service bind9 restart

- Stopping domain name service... bind9
  WARNING: key file (/etc/bind/rndc.key) exists, but using default configuration file (/etc/bind/rndc.conf)

named: Kein Prozess gefunden

named: Kein Prozess gefunden

named: Kein Prozess gefunden
                                                                         [ OK ]

- Starting domain name service... bind9                                 [ OK ]

root@mach:~#

Do you have any idea what this is about? I already tried deleting the /etc/bind/rndc.conf, but this leads to the dns not starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not only remove the rndc.conf but also add the following to named.conf:

```
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";
    controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953
    allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};
```

If you restart bind now the error should go away.

Comment: As soon as i do that, i get the following output:

Comment: match@h1804:/etc/bind# service bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused
named: Kein Prozess gefunden
named: Kein Prozess gefunden
named: Kein Prozess gefunden
                                                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                 [ OK ]

Comment: match@h1804:/etc/bind# service bind9 restart
 * Stopping domain name service... bind9                                        rndc: connection to remote host closed
This may indicate that
* the remote server is using an older version of the command protocol,
* this host is not authorized to connect,
* the clocks are not synchronized, or
* the key is invalid.
named: Kein Prozess gefunden
named: Kein Prozess gefunden
                                                                         [ OK ]
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                 [ OK ]

Comment: have you checked the file permissions on the key? i think they should be 644

Comment: The permissions were already set to 644. But even changing them to 777 didn't work out.